# Using a typedef enum outside of a class that was declared inside the class

Tags: c++, class, typedef, enumeration

In C++, I have something like this:

```
namespace myNS
{
    class A
    {
        public:
        typedef enum A_ENUMS { NONE, ALL } A_ENUMS;
    };
}
```

I want to access that typedef, maybe with something like this:

```
namespace myNS
{
    struct ASettings
    {
        myNS::A::A_ENUMS myASetting;
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error that the A does not declare a type. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Thank you for the suggestions and help. After suggestions, I updated the code. I was missing the fact that there is a namespace involved in this also. It works now.

Comment: Are you including the header where `A` is defined?

Comment: They are both declared in the same file. With the struct below the class, as I have in the example.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete example that reproduces the problem. Additionally, compiler + version would be helpful. [Live example w/o problems](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d0070c62d111b67)

Comment: [Seems to work for me](http://ideone.com/nIoAGv) after fixing typos.  If it doesn't work for you then you need to supply enough real code to demonstrate the actual issue.

Comment: @Jomnipotent17: Don't edit you post to invalidate previous answers... and remove your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Updated section above. The namespace needed to be included.

Answer (score 2):

Your typedef/enum declaration is private. Make it public and you will be able to access it from outside the class.

```
class A {
public:
    typedef enum A_ENUMS { NONE, ALL } A_ENUMS;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the public: declaration in my example, but it is public in my real code. I edited the original question to clarify.

Comment: In that case your code should compile. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I fixed it. These are also inside a namespace, and I forgot to include that; e.g. NamespaceName::A::A_ENUMS.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ classes the default access is private, so your type is not accessible from the struct. Use

```
class A
{
public:
 typedef enum A_ENUMS { NONE, ALL } A_ENUMS;
};
```

However, C++ is not C, and you do not need to use typedefs in the way normally used in C. Try:

```
class A
{
public:
 enum A_ENUMS { NONE, ALL };
};
```

It will work the same without unnecessary elements.

Answer (score 1):

You make 2 mistakes:

1. typdef != typedef (mistyping)
2. You forget class visibity.

Your code after corrections:

```
class A
{
public:
    typedef enum { NONE, ALL } A_ENUMS;
};

struct ASettings
{
  A::A_ENUMS myASetting;
};

int
main()
{
}
```

If you have normal C++11 support then you can rewrite enumeration with class scope like this:

```
typedef enum class A
{
  NONE, ALL
} A;
```

Cheers.